# Custom Android Gallery without ContentResolver

Tags: android, gallery, multi-select, android-contentresolver

I want to create functionality to upload media files to my server. So i need to create custom Gallery with multiselection. I can achieve this using RecyclerView and data from ContentResolver like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457404/custom-gallery-with-images-and-videos-in-android-to-select-multiple-items) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android). But this way is VERY long! It takes up to 60 seconds to load all media files via ContentProvider.
I see some Gallery apps in PlayMarket:

1) [Simple Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.gallery)

2) [Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flayvr.flayvr)

And there are a lot of similar apps. All of them load media on fly, without any delay.

Can anybody tell me how can i obtain all local photos and videos URLs? Do i need to go through all files and folders and collect URLs with specific suffixes?

Comment: Load small `thumbnails` not media files directly.

Comment: "So i need to create custom Gallery with multiselection" -- or, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. "It takes up to 60 seconds to load all media files via ContentProvider" -- use method tracing, `Log` statements, or other techniques to determine precisely where you are spending your time. "Can anybody tell me how can i obtain all local photos and videos URLs?" -- querying `MediaStore` works just fine.